# Operator >= not compatible with types tuple() and uint256

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, openzeppelin

I’m trying to return the balance of msg.sender from an external contract, but when I try to compare pair.balanceOf() to an uint256, it tells me they are not comparable.

I’m using Solidity 0.8.0 on Remix with OpenZeppelin contracts.

```
interface TokenInterface {
    function balanceOf(address account) view external;
}

contract Contract {
    address public tokenAddress = 0xc5d63121bA479BAeb666a896e84283a1a0AefAe6;

    TokenInterface token = TokenInterface(tokenAddress);

    function stake(uint256 amount) public {
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount, "Insufficient balance.");

        ...

    }
}
```

The other contract is an ERC20 built with OpenZeppelin.

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because function `balanceOf()` in your interface is not returning any value, so the `require` in function `stake()` can't compare balance with amount.

You need to update the interface to return the balance:

```
interface TokenInterface {
    function balanceOf(address account) view external returns(uint256);
}
```